# Adding a middle footer erases page titles

Tags: css, themes, bigcartel

I'm trying to add into the FOUNDRY theme this middle footer with some contact info and it looks really nice in the website! But when I add this middle footer, the titles of the pages go off (you can see there are there as you can go with the mouse, it's like the letters are in white over a white layout).

Can you help me out trying to have that cute footer and the page titles? THANKS IN ADVANCE!

I'm writting this code between the social media icons and the link pages:

```
<div class="Footer-middle">
    <div class="Footer-business">
        <div class="Footer-business-info">
            <div class="Footer-business-info-item">
                <style>
                    body {
                        color:white;
                    }
                </style> Es Mercadal, Menorca
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="Footer-business-info-item">
                tunkicrafts@gmail.com | 0034 699961328
            </div>  
            <br> 
            <div class="Footer-business-info-item">
                All content copyright Tunki Crafts © 2019. All rights reserved.
            </div>
            <br>             
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI, Can you please add jsfiddle link or code snippet.thanks

Comment: I have literally no idea what is that. Sorry, not even an amateur :( I found that if I have that footer in white, the titles of the pages will change as well. Can you help me trying to change only the color of the added footer, please?

Comment: add css also code. also an working example.. so we can understand it better.thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help Xenio! I don't know how I fix it, but it's already working on! YAY!